# Posting value to database laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

I'm trying to add a description to my thumbnail but it won't update in my database.

Can you guys see why?

The only `thumb_description` won't update.

Fillables are filled. When i did `$content->save()` it will return true.

**Controller:**

```
public function detail(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $content = Content_blocks::find($id);

        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                $folder = 'uploads';
                $name = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
                $store = $request->image->store($folder, 'public');
                $file = pathinfo(Storage::url($store));
                $thumb_description = $request->input('thumb_description');

                $thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
                $thumbnail->name = $file['filename'];
                $thumbnail->extenstion = $file['extension'];
                $thumbnail->path = $folder;
                $thumbnail->thumb_description = $thumb_description;
                $thumbnail->save();
                $content->thumbnail_id = $thumbnail->id;

            }

            $content->title = $request->input('title');
            $content->description = $request->input('description');
            $content->link = $request->input('link');
            $content->linkname = $request->input('linkname');
            $content->order = $request->input('order');
            $content->contentcategory_id = $request->input('categorie');
            $content->thumbnail->thumb_description = $request->input('thumb_description');


            if ($request->input('ontkoppel') === 'deletion') {
                Thumbnail::find($content->thumbnail_id)->delete();
            }

            // dd($content->thumbnail->thumb_description);
            $content->save();


            return redirect('admin/content/webcategorie/homepage/contentblocks/' . $content->content_id);
        }
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Thumbnail extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        "thumb_description",
        "name",
        "path",
        "extenstion"
    ];
    protected $table = 'thumbnail';

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Content::class);
    }

    public static function getFile($id)
    {
        $thumbnail = self::find($id);

        if ($thumbnail === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $url = sprintf('%s/%s.%s', $thumbnail->path, $thumbnail->name, $thumbnail->extenstion);

        return Storage::disk('public')->url($url);
    }
    public static function getDescription($id)
    {
        $thumbnail = self::find($id);

        if ($thumbnail === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $description = $thumbnail->thumb_description;

        return $description;
    }
}
```

**Migration**

```
   */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('thumbnail', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('path', 150);
        $table->string('extenstion', 10);
        $table->text('thumb_description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Post in chrome dev tools**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryfun4SMk5TA604OZE
```

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thumb_description"

bruyanga

Comment: Only thumb_description won't update? Is it only update or both update and add/insert? Is 'thumb_description' set in the post? Double check that (you can use Inspect > Network tab in Chrome)

Comment: dd($request->input('thumb_description'); to make sure the description is actually available with the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$content->save();` will only save the attributes on `$content` and not its relationships.

Try `$content->push();` instead which should cascade through the loaded relationships and save all related models as well.

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_push

Comment: That did the job! Thanks!